# Buttons disappearing after click event to toggle css classes

Tags: jquery

I added the toggle class to my click handler and when I run the webapp and click on one of the divs to toggle its class, the dynamic table and divs disappear.

The code in question is..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var MyResult;
        $("div").click(function () {

            $("div").toggle(function () {
                $("div").addClass("CheckBoxSubjects");
            }, function () {
                $("div").removeClass("CheckBoxSubjects");
            });

            var divID = this.id;

            MyResult = MyResult + divID + ",";
            $("#NewResult").text(MyResult);

        });
    });
```

with the dynamic table, its creating divs too and I've already set the class for the divs when everything gets created.

I'm thinking I have the code messed up, because it looks as though it should work (to me anyways), but since I am not fluent with jquery, chances are I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: From what I can see it should be `$(document).ready(function () {
    var MyResult = '';
    $("div").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("CheckBoxSubjects");
        var divID = this.id;

        MyResult = MyResult + divID + ",";
        $("#NewResult").text(MyResult);
    });
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny,  1.11.0 is being used. Which part of the html do you need? the table and divs are being made in c#

Comment: can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nzueU/1/) to recreate your case

Comment: I edited the fiddle, but I don't think I did it right because it is showing the data but the css isn't running. I have only used JSFiddle once or twice

Comment: can you share edited fiddle link(hopefully you have saved after editing it)

Comment: here is the link...http://jsfiddle.net/nzueU/2/

Comment: your css rules are wrong, the `td` is not a child of the div - it is the other way div is a child of td

Comment: where is the `NewResult` element and what is expected to happen

Comment: the NewResult, is just a div thats being treated as a placeholder for keeping track of all the divs I click, its putting the id's in it

Comment: if you click a div twice then what should happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47617/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user2970223)

Comment: also see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nzueU/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ids = [];
    $("div").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        var divID = this.id;

        var index = $.inArray(this.id, ids);
        if (index > -1) {
            ids.splice(index,1);
        } else {
            ids.push(this.id);
        }
        $("#NewResult").text(ids.join());
    });
});
```

then

```
.CheckBoxSubjects {
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #78E389;
    width: 122px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.CheckBoxBorder {
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    width: 58px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
.CheckBoxSubjects.selected {
    background-color:#78E389;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bSDUc/)